# How can i make this javascript code more concise is there a way to group them?

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator

So I have this list of ternary operators is there a way to make this more concise?

```
var modalURL = window.location.hash;
modalURL == "#link-1" ? (linkID = "link-1") + showModal(linkID) : null;
modalURL == "#link-2" ? (linkID = "link-2") + showModal(linkID) : null;
modalURL == "#link-3" ? (linkID = "link-3") + showModal(linkID) : null;
modalURL == "#link-4" ? (linkID = "link-4") + showModal(linkID) : null;
modalURL == "#link-5" ? (linkID = "link-5") + showModal(linkID) : null;
```

I'm trying to make this more concise

Comment: That's not how you should use ternary operator. It returns a value, which you're supposed to use. Is it possible `modalUrl` contains a value out of range of `link1 - link5`?

Comment: Consider using a function?

Comment: If you just want to replace the leading `#` and call the  `showModal` function: `showModal(modalURL.slice(1))`. You don't need all those conditions.

Comment: If the URL hash must be in the range of `link-1` to `link-5`, then you can use a regex: `if (/^#link-[1-5]$/.test(modalURL)) { ... }`

Comment: You can read more about ternary operators here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Answer (score 0):

Most concise would be just a function

```
const showModal = _ => {
  let linkID = window.location.hash.slice(1);

  if (linkID) {
    // do things with the id
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with a dynamic loop:

```
    var modalURL = window.location.hash;
    for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
      if (modalURL === `#link-${i}`) {
        linkID = `link-${i}`;
        showModal(linkID);
        return;
      }
    }
```